# mailto in Java?

Tags: java, email

I am trying to set a hyperlink in my eclipse java project.
when someone clicks on a button, it should open up an email client along with the given
email id. is it possible to implement it with java.awt.Desktop?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is possible using  [desktop.mail()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#mail%28java.net.URI%29)

```
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
String message = "mailto:dummy@domain.com?subject=First%20Email";
URI uri = URI.create(message);
desktop.mail(uri);
```

and regarding the `mailto` URI you have to create it yourself.

> A mailto: URI can specify message fields including "to", "cc",
>   "subject", "body", etc. See [The mailto URL scheme (RFC 2368)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368.txt) for the
>   mailto: URI specification details.

Comment: Ran Rag, I just got home and tried it out. I wrote 

Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
String message = "mailto:dummy@domain.com?subject=First%20Email";
URI uri = URI.create(message);
desktop.mail(uri);

and replaced the email id with existing one, and an error message pops up underlining URI.create saying URI.create cannot be resolved to a type?

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with [`java.awt.Desktop.mail(URI mailtoURI)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#mail%28java.net.URI%29) ??

**edit**

as for usage:

```
   Desktop desktop = getDesktop(); 
   desktop.mail(new URI("mailto:name@hotmail.com"));
```

You need to construct an `URI` instance and pass it to `Destkop.mail`.

Here's a [helpful wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto) about constructing `mailto` URIs.

Comment: Could I write:

Desktop desktop = null;
desktop = getDesktop();
desktop.browse(new URI("name@hotmail.com"));

?

Comment: @PitaSivam: It will not send email to the user.You have to use `Desktop.mail`

Comment: no, better use `dektop.mail()` as that's what it is for. `browse()` will open a browser (which in turn can open the email client). two steps instead of one.

Comment: Desktop desktop = null;
desktop = getDesktop();
desktop.mail(name@hotmail.com);

Does it sound right?