# Java RFC2368 mailto parser

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, mime, mailto, rfc2368

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java mailto to MIME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694972/java-mailto-to-mime)

I've been looking for a Java mailto parser to no avail.  There is mailTo.java which is perfect but requires Android SDK which I would rather not pull into this project (but may consider if that's the best I can find).

Similar to [mailto in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290408/mailto-in-java) but cannot use Desktop as this is a web app.  Also similar to [Parsing query strings on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667278/parsing-query-strings-in-java) but 1) am looking more specifically for mailto solution.  Apache's `URLEncodedUtils` is not a solution because mailto is opaque and while I was satisfied with hacking out the prefix to get the query arguments using this method, it has no knowledge of how to parse the to, cc, etc. parts rendering it incomplete.

Comment: Take the MailTo and Uri from Android and remove the Parcel dependency, looks straight forward and you end up with well tested code.

Comment: Parsing a mailto link is not the same thing as converting a mailto link into a MIME message.  Don't know where the closers got that idea.  I followed the comment, which would not at all have applied to the question it was duplicated from, and built the rest of the utility from there.  But in any case, this is figured out so don't care much.

Comment: The linked question has this hidden within: ".. at least fill in the parts of it that are contained within the mailto link".